# Cannot set property 'y' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently trying to load and display a .stl file using three.js using this code:

```
var stlLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
stlLoader.load('assets/Cap.stl', function (object){
    object.position.y = - 100;  
    scene.add(object);
    console.log("Object inserted.");  
    fitCameraToObject(camera,object,2,controls);
    controls.update();
    animate();
},
function ( xhr ) {
    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
},
function (err) 
{
    console.error(err);
} 
);
```

(Lines 142-158)

But I receive this error in my console upon loading my page:

```
webGLLoader.js:156 TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined
    at webGLLoader.js:144
    at Object.onLoad (STLLoader.js:80)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:35998)
(anonymous) @ webGLLoader.js:156
(anonymous) @ STLLoader.js:86
(anonymous) @ three.js:35998
load (async)
load @ three.js:35976
load @ STLLoader.js:76
(anonymous) @ webGLLoader.js:143
```

I'm unsure as to why this is happening as I'm able to set an objects position this same way when using other loaders.

Comment: add console.log(object.position); before Line 3, to see if it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An STL file contains only geometry. `STLLoader` returns a [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) object. A `BufferGeometry` object does not have a `position` property, but you can use it to create a `Mesh`, which does.

```js
// three.js r113

let loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load("./file.stl", function(geo){
  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"red"}) );
  mesh .position.y = -100;
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```